# $.get problem with Chrome

Tags: jquery, plugins, google-chrome

I'm programming a plugin for Google Chrome, but the problem is, that I can't get working jQuery $.get calls. Console says: Failed to load resource.

//popup.html

```
    <script>             
        _get = function(url, callback) {
            console.log("sending get");
            chrome.extension.sendRequest({action:'get',url:url}, callback);
        }

        _get('https://www.meebo.com/mcmd/start.cgi?type=mobile&allowIPChange=true', function(data) {
            alert(data);
      });
    </script>
```

//background.html

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onRequest(request, sender, callback) {
        if (request.action == 'getJSON') {
            $.getJSON(request.url, callback);
        }
        if (request.action == 'ajax') {
            $.ajax({
                type : request.type,    
                url : request.url,
                async : async,
                success : callback
            });
        }
        if (request.action == 'get') {
            $.get(request.url, callback);
        }

        if (request.action == 'post') {
            $.post(request.url, request.data, callback);
        }
    }

    chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(onRequest);
</script>
```

Comment: Hm, could you explain please how the parts are wired? You are obviously using two different ways for performing requests ( chrome built-in and jquery ). how is the first snippet related to the problem?

Comment: The problem is that you can't use jQuery-ajax-functions in content files, because of the security restrictions of Chrome, so I'm performing ajax requests in popup.html, which I sent through chrome.extension.sendRequest({action:'get',url:url}, callback);. They are catched in background.html with chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(onRequest); and executed, because backgroundpages have no restrictions. The part which is failing is $.get(request.url, callback); but the function is called, but result is console output "Failed to load resource"

Answer (score 0):

Solution for the problem is to use only http instead of https, because the ssl certificate of meebo is not valid.